# Making a data figure with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have an issue for plotting my curves with tikz.
All I am obtaining is the legend, but no curve, neither graphic or axes ....

Any help is welcomed !
Thank you

Here is the (simplified) code

```
%%% TikZ packages and styles %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{120}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest} 
\pgfplotsset{plot coordinates/math parser=false}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}


% TikZ styles (nodes and squares)
\tikzstyle{itnode}=[circle,thick,draw]
\tikzstyle{itnodesq}=[rectangle,thick,text centered,text width=5em,minimum height=3em,draw]
\tikzstyle{init} = [pin edge={<-,thin,black}]



\begin{document}
\setlength{\figurewidth}{0.65\columnwidth}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{center}
    \scriptsize
    \begin{tikzpicture} \begin{axis}[
     width=\figurewidth,
   height=0.48830242510699\figurewidth,
  scale only axis,
  xmin=5, xmax=10,
  xlabel={Temps (s)},
  xmajorgrids,
  ymin=40, ymax=95,
  ylabel={Y},
  ymajorgrids,
  axis lines*=left,
  legend style={at={(1.03,1)},anchor=north west,draw=black,fill=white,legend cell align=left}]
  \addplot [
  color=blue,
  solid
  ]
  coordinates{
  (4.98725704809287,67)
  (5.00027860696517,66)
  (5.01330016583748,64)
  (5.02632172470978,64)};
  \addlegendentry{Node 2};
  \addplot [
  color=green!50!black,
  solid]
  coordinates{
  (4.98725704809287,89)
  (5.00027860696517,81)
  (5.01330016583748,82)
  (5.02632172470978,82)};
  \addlegendentry{Node 3};
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}%
      \end{center}
      \label{fig:example_plot}
  \end{figure}

  \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)). Reproducing the problem will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. Please check your code style, you can edit the question.

Comment: You have `\begin{center}` but `\end{centlegend}`, which I assume is an error.

Comment: Your y-values are outside of your range given by `ymin` and `ymax`.

Comment: Torjorn and epR8GaYuh, you were right (it was an error in the modification of the code before putting it here), but I still have the same issue.

Comment: Also, you have x-values between 4.98 and  5.02, but for some reason you've set `xmin=5,xmax=10`. And in your updated code you've forgot to define the `\figurewidth` length.

Comment: Thank it was the \figurewidth that was missing !! Thanks so much ! Have a nice day :-)

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that you expect something like this:

[image]

- since your `\figurewidth` is unknown, I use default image sizes
- as you can read in above comments, your coordinates range is very tiny compare to declared `xmin` -- `xmax` range, so the drawn circle (it is present on your image) is almost invisible
- from your code snipped I delet all what is not relevant to this graph

MWE:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
    \scriptsize
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[
%     width=\figurewidth,
%   height=0.48830242510699\figurewidth,
  scale only axis,
%  xmin=4, xmax=6,
  xlabel={Temps (s)},
  xmajorgrids,
  ymin=60, ymax=90,
  ylabel={Y},
  ymajorgrids,
  axis lines*=left,
  legend style={at={(1.03,1)},anchor=north west,draw=black,fill=white,legend cell align=left}]
  \addplot[
  color=blue,
  solid
  ]
  coordinates{
  (4.98725704809287,67)
  (5.00027860696517,66)
  (5.01330016583748,64)
  (5.02632172470978,64)};
  \addplot[
  color=green!50!black,
  solid]
  coordinates{
  (4.98725704809287,89)
  (5.00027860696517,81)
  (5.01330016583748,82)
  (5.02632172470978,82)};
  \legend{Node2, Node 3};
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```